# Australian Based Heroku-Like Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been using Heroku for client rails sites for some time now.

I now have a new client and would like to use Heroku for development and production, however the client is concerned about storing their data outside Australia. There are apparently some privacy, liability, and legal issues with where data is stored for their type of business.

Can anyone suggest a Heroku like service provider based in Australia?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this company hosts Rails apps in the cloud, and is based in Australia: `<redacted>`

This is an extremely strange request, however.  I'm not quite sure that using Heroku and storing files on S3 or similar would be a big issue.

**EDIT:  It appears as though the site posted originally is no longer active.**

Comment: Thanks for the link. For my part I agree with you about the strangeness of the request, however there are about 450 separate laws according to this Sydney Morning Herald article (http://www.smh.com.au/it-pro/cloud/is-it-legal-to-send-your-data-overseas-20111011-1lic0.html) that are causing a lot of confusion here. The US trade people have also criticised the Aus Govt about warning business to keep data hosted in Australia. My client happens also to be in an extremely privacy oriented business.

Comment: It's not really that odd. I've had US-based enterprise clients ask us to confirm that we store the data we hold on their behalf in US-based systems. Of course, in the case of Heroku that's so.

Comment: This is very common request.  Most corporates & Government clients want their sites hosted in-country.